# Query table with array_agg of ALL previous positions, excluding current position

Tags: postgresql, array-agg

I have a database table with:

```
id | date       | position | name
--------------------------------------
1  | 2016-06-29 | 9        | Ben Smith
2  | 2016-06-29 | 1        | Ben Smith
3  | 2016-06-29 | 5        | Ben Smith
4  | 2016-06-29 | 6        | Ben Smith
5  | 2016-06-30 | 2        | Ben Smith
6  | 2016-06-30 | 2        | Tom Brown
7  | 2016-06-29 | 4        | Tom Brown
8  | 2016-06-30 | 2        | Tom Brown
9  | 2016-06-30 | 1        | Tom Brown
```

How can I query the table efficiently so that I can get a new column using array_agg().

I have already tried the following query however its incredibly slow and also wrong as it doesn't group the previous_positions by the name column:

```
SELECT 
j.*,
(SELECT array_agg(id) FROM jockeys j2 WHERE j2.id < j.id)
FROM jockeys j
```

I expect the table output to look like this

```
id | date       | position | name      | previous_positions
----------------------------------------------------------
1  | 2016-06-29 | 9        | Ben Smith | {}
2  | 2016-06-29 | 1        | Ben Smith | {9}
3  | 2016-06-29 | 5        | Ben Smith | {9,1}
4  | 2016-06-29 | 6        | Ben Smith | {9,1,5}
5  | 2016-06-30 | 2        | Ben Smith | {9,1,5,6}
6  | 2016-06-30 | 2        | Tom Brown | {}
7  | 2016-06-29 | 4        | Tom Brown | {2}
8  | 2016-06-30 | 2        | Tom Brown | {2,4}
9  | 2016-06-30 | 1        | Tom Brown | {2,4,2}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the `WINDOW` clause for array_agg

```
SELECT 
j.* ,  array_agg(position) over w as previous_positions
FROM jockeys j
WINDOW w as
(  partition by name ORDER BY id rows between 
     unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
     )
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=4399055d1b7d8ad4a3a16aeffa0ca0e1)

Comment: How would I also get the median of the previous_positions?

For all, last_20, last_50 etc. I have been trying it on the created arrays but its really slow, was wondering whether it would be easier to calc these at the same time as the grouping?

Comment: @LukeByrne : Please ask a new question.

Comment: @KaushikNakyak will do

Comment: @KaushikNakyak  Posted update [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56015072/query-table-with-array-agg-median-of-all-previous-positions-last-10-last-50-e)

Comment: @KaushikNakyak I have new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57354543/query-table-with-sum-of-all-previous-positions-excluding-current-position) if you are able to help?