# Query table with sum of ALL previous positions, excluding current position

Tags: postgresql

I have a database table with:

```
id | date       | position | name
--------------------------------------
1  | 2016-06-29 | 9        | Ben Smith
2  | 2016-06-29 | 1        | Ben Smith
3  | 2016-06-29 | 5        | Ben Smith
4  | 2016-06-29 | 6        | Ben Smith
5  | 2016-06-30 | 2        | Ben Smith
6  | 2016-06-30 | 2        | Tom Brown
7  | 2016-06-29 | 4        | Tom Brown
8  | 2016-06-30 | 2        | Tom Brown
9  | 2016-06-30 | 1        | Tom Brown
```

How can I query the table efficiently so that I can get a new column using sum().

I expect the table output to look like this

```
id | date       | position | name      | races | wins | places
--------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 2016-06-29 | 9        | Ben Smith | 1     | 0    | 0
2  | 2016-06-29 | 1        | Ben Smith | 2     | 1    | 0
3  | 2016-06-29 | 5        | Ben Smith | 3     | 1    | 0
4  | 2016-06-29 | 6        | Ben Smith | 4     | 1    | 0
5  | 2016-06-30 | 2        | Ben Smith | 5     | 1    | 1
6  | 2016-06-30 | 2        | Tom Brown | 1     | 0    | 2
7  | 2016-06-29 | 4        | Tom Brown | 1     | 0    | 2
8  | 2016-06-30 | 2        | Tom Brown | 2     | 0    | 3
9  | 2016-06-30 | 1        | Tom Brown | 4     | 1    | 3
```

Comment: You should explain clearly how each column is arrived at rather than expecting readers to spend time in understanding it. Also, show us the query you've tried.

Comment: @KaushikNayak Sorry for not posting code, I had no idea how to get started. I have taken from the answer below and expanded on it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this can easily be done using window functions:

```
select id, date, position, name, 
       row_number(*) over (partition by name, date order by id) as races,
       count(*) filter (where position = 1) over (partition by name, date)  as wins
from the_table;
```

I don't understand the logic to calculate the `places` column though.

Comment: i think places : position =  2

Comment: @FatFreddy: I thought that too, but that doesn't work for Tom Brown (only two position = 2 and on different days)

Answer (score 0):

@FatFreddy @a_horse_with_no_name

Thanks for getting me started, this is what I came up with. Do you think it can be improved on?

```
WITH runners AS (
    SELECT 
        r.*,
        CASE
            WHEN position = 1 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS win,
        CASE
            WHEN position = 2 THEN 1
            WHEN position = 3 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS place
    FROM 
        runners r
    ORDER BY id
)   
SELECT 
    date, 
    r.id, 
    r.position, 
    name,
    row_number(*) OVER foo AS races,
    sum(win) OVER foo AS win,
    sum(place) OVER foo AS place
FROM 
    runners r
LEFT JOIN markets m ON m.id = r.market_id
WINDOW foo AS (PARTITION BY name) ORDER BY r.id)
```